# C: GTK+ 3.0 (3.20) - Cross-Compile from GNU/Linux (Arch Linux) to Windows

Tags: c, linux, windows, cross-compiling, gtk3

I need to cross-compile GTK+ application from GNU/Linux (Arch Linux) to Windows. I have already tried to use `mingw32`, but it does not see *all libraries (including c's standard library!)*. So, I need to: find the standard libary; find *all other (glib, gio, gtk, etc)* libraries. But there's a problemm - I cannot find them. I also cannot compile from Windows. What must I do?

Answer (score 7):

You can find the binaries for gtk 3 for windows [on source forge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/) or on http://win32builder.gnome.org/.

Once you have extracted them, you can follow this [tutorial](http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/45) steps:

**1) Install the compilation toolchain**

- Install the GCC compiler for Windows (namely MinGW, [Arch Linux doc of package](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MinGW_package_guidelines)):

  `#pacman -S migw-w64`
- Download the latest all-in-one bundle ZIP archive directly from the official website (here's a direct [link](http://win32builder.gnome.org/gtk+-bundle_3.6.4-20130921_win32.zip))
- Adapt GTK+ to its location : In a terminal, move to the "gtk3-win32" folder you just created. For example: `$cd /opt/gtk3-win32`
  then do :

  `find -name '*.pc' | while read pc; do sed -e "s@^prefix=.*@prefix=$PWD@" -i "$pc"; done`

**2) Compile**

- We will tell `pkg-config` to locate GTK+3 libraries in our custom path. If you extracted to `/opt/gtk3-win32`:

  `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/gtk3-win32/lib/pkgconfig`

  We are ready to compile a sample C source ! Let's use a command in this style :

  ```
  i586-mingw32msvc-gcc source.c -o executable.exe `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0
  ```

A new executable should have been created if everything went well.
It won't run on our Linux system, because it's targeting Windows !

**3) Release**

- Create a folder containing the binary and the Windows .dll files. If you extracted to `/opt/gtk3-win32`:

  ```
  mkdir ~/distri
  cp executable.exe ~/distri
  cp /opt/gtk3-win32/bin/*.dll ~/distri
  ```
- Here we go ! Transfer this folder to a Windows box. Double-click on the executable and...

Comment: Good, but what if i need gtk3.20, not gtk 3.6? There's giant differences between them. Almost like gtk2 and gtk3

Comment: The latest version on source forge is 3.18. I am not sure 3.20 has been ported yet.

Comment: My current version: 3.20.9

Comment: Do you mean on Windows or on Linux? I have 3.20 on Linux but I am not sure it has been ported to Windows platform yet. I wouldn't be surprised if the Windows port was a good few month behind the Linux release.

Comment: On linux. (cts)

Answer (score 1):

The following instructions are for gcc 5.3.0 (thread model: posix) and gtk+ 3.20.4

#### Install [msys2](https://msys2.github.io/) on windows

#### Install gtk3 files and copy the files

After installation, in msys2 shell

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-gtk3

cd /mingw32
tar cfz c:/temp/mingw32.tar.gz
```

#### Ensure matching gcc version on Arch Linux

For gcc 5.3.0, edit /etc/pacman.conf

```
[core]
Server = https://archive.archlinux.org/repos/2016/05/10/$repo/os/$arch

[extra]
Server = https://archive.archlinux.org/repos/2016/05/10/$repo/os/$arch

[community]
Server = https://archive.archlinux.org/repos/2016/05/10/$repo/os/$arch
```

In case of upgrade

```
pacman -Syu
```

In case of downgrade

```
pacman -Syyuu
```

Later Arch Linux version seem to have gcc 6.1.1 that might be incompatible with msys2 gcc. A virtual machine might be a good idea for an Arch Linux installation that will not be upgraded (i.e. no security updates).

#### Copy files to linux

Unpack *mingw32.tar.gz* on linux, for example */opt/mingw32*

#### Modify pkg-config files

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's,^prefix=.*,prefix=/opt/mingw32,' /opt/mingw32/lib/pkgconfig/*.pc
```

#### Set PKG_CONFIG_PATH

For example, before executing a configure script

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/mingw32/lib/pkgconfig
```

Comment: I noticed that these gtk3 dll libraries depend on *libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll* i.e. the exception model is dw2. The compiler that comes with Arch Linux mingw-w64-gcc package has been built with option `--disable-dw2-exceptions`.

Comment: I don't have windows system